# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError) You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, zshrc

I'm rendering write permissions to bundle or install gems on my rails app.

It's not recommended but I have tried using
`sudo gemname install` and it does not work for me either.

Im unable to connect after running `bundle install`

here is the issue

`An error occurred while installing puma (4.3.3), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that gem install puma -v '4.3.3' succeeds before bundling.`

Then I run
`gem install puma -v '4.3.3'`

and rendered
`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError) You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.`

I thought this may be helpful to know. Here is a list of my local gems

```
benchmark (default: 0.1.0)
bigdecimal (default: 2.0.0)
bundler (2.1.4, 1.17.3)
cgi (default: 0.1.0)
codecov (0.2.7)
colorize (0.8.1)
csv (default: 3.1.2)
date (default: 3.0.0)
dbm (default: 1.1.0)
delegate (default: 0.1.0)
did_you_mean (default: 1.4.0)
docile (1.3.2)
etc (default: 1.1.0)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.4.1)
forwardable (default: 1.3.1)
getoptlong (default: 0.1.0)
io-console (default: 0.5.6)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.2)
irb (default: 1.2.6)
json (default: 2.3.0)
logger (default: 1.4.2)
matrix (default: 0.2.0)
minitest (5.13.0)
mutex_m (default: 0.1.0)
net-pop (default: 0.1.0)
net-smtp (default: 0.1.0)
net-telnet (0.2.0)
nio4r (2.5.4)
observer (default: 0.1.0)
open3 (default: 0.1.0)
openssl (default: 2.1.2)
ostruct (default: 0.2.0)
power_assert (1.1.7)
prime (default: 0.1.1)
pstore (default: 0.1.0)
psych (default: 3.1.0)
racc (default: 1.4.16)
rake (13.0.1)
rdoc (default: 6.2.1)
readline (default: 0.0.2)
readline-ext (default: 0.1.0)
reline (default: 0.1.5)
rexml (default: 3.2.3)
rss (default: 0.2.8)
sdbm (default: 1.0.0)
simplecov (0.19.0)
simplecov-html (0.12.3)
singleton (default: 0.1.0)
stringio (default: 0.1.0)
strscan (default: 1.0.3)
test-unit (3.3.4)
timeout (default: 0.1.0)
tracer (default: 0.1.0)
uri (default: 0.10.0)
webrick (default: 1.6.0)
xmlrpc (0.3.0)
yaml (default: 0.1.0)
zlib (default: 1.1.0)
```

I thought this had something to do with not having x-code command line.

I have downloaded x-code command line and updated my system software and I am still rendering this error.

I think it might have something to do with my

~/.zshrc file

here it is

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/mvizcaino/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to automatically update without prompting.
# DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS=true

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
alias zshconfig= "mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
#export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

# Ruby with rbenv initialize
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"

export GEM_HOME=/Users/mvizcaino/gems

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"

alias brewup='brew update; brew upgrade; brew cleanup; brew doctor'
```

I'm not sure what else could be causing this but I'm pretty much stuck on this error.

Comment: this is a more linux and permissions related question, you probably have your gem's folder under sudo user ownership, what command you meant with 'sudo install'?

Comment: im using mac catalina. Most articles point to using `sudo gem install gemname`

Comment: avoid using sudo to install your gems, your are basically telling the system to execute the program as a sudo user, but when you are using your app you are using it as your personal user, in order to work right now you should use sudo ruby app.rb or sudo rails server... depending on what are you doing... which is fundamentally wrong

Comment: I never use rails on mac, but this guide seems pretty straightforward https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.15-catalina

Comment: not using `sudo` doesn't work either. This guide was helpful but the step that wasn't compatible for me was running this command `sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /`

Comment: Wait. The question implies you’re trying `sudó bundle install` but mistyped that in the question (we assume this because you list your gemfile. But that last comment clears up that your install command is something else entirely, not bundler. Reword the question to more clearly show us what you run and what the full output is. No need to guess that gemfile or zsh profiles are relevant - actual command and actual output are very relevant.

Comment: @TomHarvey i added more details on here in order of events. - hopefully clears up some confusion.

Comment: Problem resolved with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74973580/3968301

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the permission problem by installing the gems locally to your project

```
bundle install --path=vendor
```

If bundler still gives you an error while installing puma, it means that your build tools are not working. The full output from `bundle install` should tell you what is wrong.

The errors are usually right above the "bundler cannot continue" message

Comment: turns out by rbenv was not configured in a global state to the internal ruby version provided by mac was throwing the error. The issue was fixed by running `rbenv global 2.6.5` which is the ruby version im using on this project

Comment: Adding to the previous comment by mvizm2015. His comment helped but did not fix the issue entirely. It was fixed by removing the `~/.ruby-version` file, which set the ruby version to use. It was a file created a long time ago with a totally outdated ruby version that was not installed in rbenv.

Comment: Problem resolved with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74973580/3968301